# MYSQL C# Cannot save the original characters in the table

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Im trying to save this line of characters in a table in mysql.

Here is the string value:

> @£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞ^{}\[~]|€ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà

[image]

The saved string value in the table is look like this:

> @£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå?_FG?O??ST?^{}[~]|€ÆæßÉ!"#¤%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà

[image]
I've already alter the database charset from default to **UTF8MB4** Collation **UTF8MB4_GENERAL_CI**

Here is the Query String I used:

```
"INSERT INTO Inbox (message) values  (@message);";
```

Here is the MysqlParameter I used to save the string above:

```
mySQLCommand.AddParameter(new MySqlParameter("@message", MySqlDbType.LongText), entity.message, ref parameters);
```

I've noticed that not all the characters are saved on its original form.

Do I declared an incorrect mysqlParameter? Or missed something?

Im using PhpmyAdmin version  4.5.1.

Thank you! :)

Comment: You might have to save it as a BLOB field inside database and convert it each time you want to retrieve it from DB

Comment: @Stivan thank you for this suggestion. I will try this! Let see. :)

Comment: Did you try to load back your string in c#?

Comment: did u try ascii_bin

Comment: Yes @Kalten. It loads the characters as same value in the column.

Comment: Hello @safinchacko, not yet! :) I will try also your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: also try utf8_bin..

Comment: @safinchacko how about the mysqlparameter type?

Comment: I've noticed that when I tried to insert manually the actual characters successfully save in the column. I think it's on the type of the parameter is the issue.

Comment: Since you appear to be testing an SMS application (as these are all the characters in the GSM 03.38 character set) be aware that SMS messages can be Unicode as well, meaning they could contain any character, not just Greek. So you probably want your application to handle all Unicode characters correctly. (I have no experience with PHP or MySQL, so I don't know how to fix this particular issue.)

Comment: @Stivan Hello bro, Its working now using blob data type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to set is the collation type of the database.

***Collation type should be set to UTF_8mb4_general_ci***

[image]

Second, set the collation type of string or text column of the table.

***Collation type should be set to UTF_8mb4_general_ci***
[image]

Finally, Set the character set of your connection.

```
SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=characters;UID=root;PASSWORD=;Charset=utf8;
```

Kindly refer on my sample source code:

```
string sSQL = @"INSERT INTO characters VALUES(0,@message);";
            ArrayList parameter = new ArrayList();
            AddParameter(new MySqlParameter("@message", MySqlDbType.String), textBox1.Text, ref parameter);
            try
            {
                var data = mySQLCommand.Instance.ExecuteScalarSQLCommand(sSQL, parameter);

                MessageBox.Show("Save!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.ToString()
                    );
            }
```

Sample entry of characters to be add to the table:

[image]

After clicking the button1. In the image below, you can see that the characters retain on its original form after the insert operation.

Hopefully this will help you on your issues.

Regards,

Lou II